# How to get element ID to show all data from clicked element using react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So, I have my component where it shows all of the products. What I want now is, when I click on one of the products to open component for displaying all of the data of clicked product. When I click, it shows me this `url`  `http://localhost:3000/products/1`.
How can I get data with this id at the end of `url`

This is component that fetch all the data from mysql:

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"


class Home extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            products: [],
            isLoaded: false
        }
    }

   componentDidMount(){
        fetch("/home")
        .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result =>{
                        return(
                            this.setState({
                                products: result,
                                isLoaded: true
                            })
                        )
            })
   }

    render(){
      if(!this.state.isLoaded){
          return(
              <h1>Loading...</h1>
          )
      }

      return (
            <div className="row text-center">
                    {this.state.products.map(elements => 
                            <div className="col-lg-6">
                                    <h1>
                                        <Link to={`products/${elements.id}`}>{elements.name}</Link> 
                                    </h1>
                            </div> 
                    )}  
            </div>
         )
    }
}
export default Home;
```

And how can I get that clicked product information here:

```
import React from "react";

class ProductDesc extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch()
            .then(res => res.json())
                .then(result =>{
                    console.log(result)
                })
    }

    render(){
        return(

        )
    }
}
export default ProductDesc;
```

Comment: Can you share your `Router` code?

Comment: @DrewReese I hope you mean on this. I'm new at this :)
 <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route path="/products/:id" component={ProductDesc} />
      </BrowserRouter>

Comment: Sure, answered below already. Where are you trying to access that `id` so I can refine my answer? In `componentDidMount` to fetch some specific data?

Comment: @DrewReese I just need to get all the data of the product that's clicked in Home component and show it in ProductDesc component. The thing is that I don't know how to fetch data of that clicked element. Hope you understand now :)

Comment: Do you have an API endpoint you are trying to hit? Does `fetch` mean something else in your app's context? Can you be more specific in what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Router` you should have a `Route` that renders `ProductDesc`.

```
<Route path="products/:id" component={ProductDesc} />
```

This will add [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) to the rendered component. You can access the route parameter from the [`match`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match) prop.

ProductDesc

```
this.props.match.params.id
```